# Verify Law of Large Numbers in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, random, average

The problem:
If a large number of fair *N*-sided dice are rolled, the average of the simulated rolls is likely to be close to the mean of 1,2,...*N* i.e. the expected value of one die. For example, the expected value of a 6-sided die is 3.5.

Given *N*, simulate 1e8 *N*-sided dice rolls by creating a vector of 1e8 uniformly distributed random integers. Return the difference between the mean of this vector and the mean of integers from 1 to *N*.

---

My code:

```
function dice_diff = loln(N)
       % the mean of integer from 1 to N    
       A = 1:N
       meanN = sum(A)/N;
% I do not have any idea what I am doing here!
       V = randi(1e8);
       meanvector = V/1e8;
       dice_diff = meanvector - meanN;
end
```

Comment: What is the question you have?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make sure everytime you ask a question that it is as clear as possible, to make it easier for other users to read.
If you check how randi works, you can see this:

> R = randi(IMAX,N) returns an N-by-N matrix containing pseudorandom
>       integer values drawn from the discrete uniform distribution on 1:IMAX.
>       randi(IMAX,M,N) or randi(IMAX,[M,N]) returns an M-by-N matrix.
>       randi(IMAX,M,N,P,...) or randi(IMAX,[M,N,P,...]) returns an
>       M-by-N-by-P-by-... array.  randi(IMAX) returns a scalar.
>       randi(IMAX,SIZE(A)) returns an array the same size as A.

So, if you want to use randi in your problem, you have to use it like this:

```
V=randi(N, 1e8,1);
```

and you need some more changes:

```
function dice_diff = loln(N)
%the mean of integer from 1 to N    
A = 1:N;
meanN = mean(A); 
V = randi(N, 1e8,1);
meanvector = mean(V);
dice_diff = meanvector - meanN;
end
```

For future problems, try using the command

```
help randi
```

And matlab will explain how the function randi (or other function) works.

Make sure to check if the code above gives the desired result

Answer (score 1):

As [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60413769/8239061), take a closer look at the use of [`randi()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randi.html). From the general case

```
X = randi([LowerInt,UpperInt],NumRows,NumColumns);  % UpperInt > LowerInt
```

you can adapt to dice rolling by

```
Rolls = randi([1 NumSides],NumRolls,NumSamplePaths);
```

as an example. Exchanging `NumRolls` and `NumSamplePaths` will yield `Rolls.'`, or `transpose(Rolls)`.

According to the [Law of Large Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers), the updated sample average after each roll should converge to the true mean, `ExpVal` (short for [expected value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value)), as the number of rolls (trials) increases. Notice that as `NumRolls` gets larger, the sample mean converges to the true mean. The image below shows this for two sample paths.

[image: Top Image showing sample mean converging per Law of Large Numbers. Bottom figure showing mean error converging to zero.]

To get the sample mean for each number of dice rolls, I used [`arrayfun()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) with

```
CumulativeAvg1 = arrayfun(@(jj)mean(Rolls(1:jj,1)),[1:NumRolls]);
```

which is equivalent to using the cumulative sum, [`cumsum()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html), to get the same result.

```
CumulativeAvg1 = (cumsum(Rolls(:,1))./(1:NumRolls).');    % equivalent
```

---

```
% MATLAB R2019a
% Create Dice
NumSides = 6;   % positive nonzero integer
NumRolls = 200;
NumSamplePaths = 2;

% Roll Dice
Rolls = randi([1 NumSides],NumRolls,NumSamplePaths);  

% Output Statistics
ExpVal = mean(1:NumSides);
CumulativeAvg1 = arrayfun(@(jj)mean(Rolls(1:jj,1)),[1:NumRolls]);
CumulativeAvgError1 = CumulativeAvg1 - ExpVal;
CumulativeAvg2 = arrayfun(@(jj)mean(Rolls(1:jj,2)),[1:NumRolls]);
CumulativeAvgError2 = CumulativeAvg2 - ExpVal;

% Plot
figure
subplot(2,1,1), hold on, box on
    plot(1:NumRolls,CumulativeAvg1,'b--','LineWidth',1.5,'DisplayName','Sample Path 1')
    plot(1:NumRolls,CumulativeAvg2,'r--','LineWidth',1.5,'DisplayName','Sample Path 2')
    yline(ExpVal,'k-')
    title('Average')
    xlabel('Number of Trials')
    ylim([1 NumSides])
subplot(2,1,2), hold on, box on
    plot(1:NumRolls,CumulativeAvgError1,'b--','LineWidth',1.5,'DisplayName','Sample Path 1')
    plot(1:NumRolls,CumulativeAvgError2,'r--','LineWidth',1.5,'DisplayName','Sample Path 2')
    yline(0,'k-')
    title('Error')
    xlabel('Number of Trials')
```